# How to make only one dropdown list to be dropped down on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, dropdown

I have three dropdown lists in horizontal which show the station names when clicking on particular line.

However, when I click on one line, all the lists are being dropped down.
Actually I want only particular list to drop, and others to stay undropped until user clicks on them.

How to achieve this?

My JS for dropping lists here:

```
;(function($) {
/* выбор города */
$('.lines_list').click(function(){
$(".stations_list").slideToggle('fast');
});
})(jQuery);
```

Live demo is here:
https://www.metroguides.net/ru/cities/kazan-metro

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the event handler on all the three dropdown. When clicking one you then tell each `".stations_list"` to slideToggle.

Try out the following code. Here it should only `slideToggle` the element that was clicked using `$( this )`.

```
;(function($) {
/* выбор города */
$('.lines_list').click(function(){
$( this ).find(".stations_list").slideToggle('fast');
});
$('ul.stations_list li').click(function(){
var tx = $(this).html();
var tv = $(this).attr('alt');
$( this ).parent().slideUp('fast');
$(".lines_list span").html(tx);
$(".lines_text").html(tv);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, not working. Now the elements are simply disappear one-by-one when clicking.

Comment: Got it, now working. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.